# 'ModelBase' object is not iterable

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

when I get all profiles from the database I take following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home//venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 241, in get
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 48, in list
    return Response(serializer.data)
  File "/home/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 768, in data
    ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
  File "/home/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 262, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/home/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 686, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
TypeError: 'ModelBase' object is not iterable
[11/Jul/2019 10:15:06] "GET /profile/ HTTP/1.1" 500 24593
Internal Server Error: /profile/
```

I easily create profile with post method but getting all profiles are problem. my **models.py** file

```
class Profile(TimeModel):
   user = models.OneToOneField('user_accounts.CustomUser', primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
   birthdate = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', null=True)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.user.email
```

in the **serializers.py**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  user = UserSerializer(read_only=True, source='user.email')
  character = CharacterSerializer()
  category = CategorySerializer()
  birthdate = serializers.DateTimeField(format='%Y-%m-%d')

   class Meta:
     model = Profile
     fields = ['user', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'birthdate', 'gender', 'image', 'category', 'character']
```

I looked at some solutions but they did not help to get it solved. As well as, I added

> bases = (models.Model,) to migrations

it did nothing. how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why have you put `source='user.email'` in the definition of the `user` field?

Comment: because I cannot create a profile without it. I am using rest social auth

Comment: @coder: but the `source` here is `user`, not its email.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what should I do? remove the source?

Comment: Yes, since if the name of the field and the source are the same, that is not necessary.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I removed but again same error is showing

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem as well as If i create profile with post it throws another error Foreign Key Constraint Failed